# App Run Outside of VS2012 Ultimate Crashes after 5-15 Seconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crash

I am having an issue that I can't seem to find the solution for anywhere on this site.  Perhaps I'm just searching the wrong terms, so now I leave it in your capable hands via a direct question.  Here it is:

Whenever I make an application using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and make a debug build or a release build then try to run either outside the IDE it crashes after about 5 to 15 seconds without any error messages/exceptions displayed.  I've tried this using a C# and VB application.  To the best of my knowledge all my .NET framework is up to date.  I had an instance of Visual Studio 2008 Professional installed prior to VS2012 Ultimate and everything worked just fine.  After I installed VS2012 Ultimate, anything that I create from it doesn't run properly.  Since then I have uninstalled both VS2008 Professional and VS2012 Ultimate, ran CCleaner, then did a complete reinstall of VS2012 Ultimate.  The problem still persists.  Also, a friend of mine brought over an .exe (he made no .dll files) to show me a program he made and the same symptoms remain on my laptop, but it works perfectly on his.

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium edition 64-bit.  Any help that can be offered is appreciated.

For simplicity, I created a blank form and here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Spoon
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you all very much for all of your assistance.

UPDATE **
This is the output from the immediate window when VS2012 Ultimate is running.

An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.  This information is also logged in "C:\Users\GoombaMaster\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml".

```
Exception details:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.
   at MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Native.Util.ConvertHresultToException(Int32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.FontFace.TryGetFontTable(OpenTypeTableTag openTypeTableTag, Byte[]& tableData)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FontFaceLayoutInfo.GetFontTable(OpenTypeTableTag openTypeTableTag)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.GsubGposTables..ctor(FontFaceLayoutInfo layout)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FontFaceLayoutInfo.ComputeTypographyAvailabilities()
   at System.Windows.Media.Typeface.CheckFastPathNominalGlyphs(CharacterBufferRange charBufferRange, Double emSize, Double scalingFactor, Double widthMax, Boolean keepAWord, Boolean numberSubstitution, CultureInfo cultureInfo, TextFormattingMode textFormattingMode, Boolean isSideways, Boolean breakOnTabs, Int32& stringLengthFit)
   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.SimpleRun.CreateSimpleTextRun(CharacterBufferRange charBufferRange, TextRun textRun, TextFormatterImp formatter, Int32 widthLeft, Boolean emergencyWrap, Boolean breakOnTabs)
   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.SimpleRun.Create(FormatSettings settings, CharacterBufferRange charString, TextRun textRun, Int32 cp, Int32 cpFirst, Int32 runLength, Int32 widthLeft, Int32 idealRunOffsetUnRounded)
   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.SimpleTextLine.Create(FormatSettings settings, Int32 cpFirst, Int32 paragraphWidth)
   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextFormatterImp.FormatLineInternal(TextSource textSource, Int32 firstCharIndex, Int32 lineLength, Double paragraphWidth, TextParagraphProperties paragraphProperties, TextLineBreak previousLineBreak, TextRunCache textRunCache)
   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextFormatterImp.FormatLine(TextSource textSource, Int32 firstCharIndex, Double paragraphWidth, TextParagraphProperties paragraphProperties, TextLineBreak previousLineBreak)
   at System.Windows.Media.FormattedText.LineEnumerator.FormatLine(TextSource textSource, Int32 textSourcePosition, Double maxLineLength, TextParagraphProperties paraProps, TextLineBreak lineBreak)
   at System.Windows.Media.FormattedText.LineEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Windows.Media.FormattedText.DrawAndCalculateMetrics(DrawingContext dc, Point drawingOffset, Boolean getBlackBoxMetrics)
   at System.Windows.Media.FormattedText.get_Metrics()
   at System.Windows.Media.FormattedText.get_Height()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Formatting.Implementation.TextInfoCache.GetTextInfo(TextRunProperties key)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Formatting.Implementation.FormattedTextSourceFactoryService.Create(ITextSnapshot sourceTextSnapshot, ITextSnapshot visualBufferSnapshot, Int32 tabSize, Double baseIndentation, Double wordWrapWidth, Double maxAutoIndent, Boolean useDisplayMode, IClassifier aggregateClassifier, ITextAndAdornmentSequencer sequencer, IClassificationFormatMap classificationFormatMap, Boolean isViewWrapEnabled)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.PerformLayout(ITextSnapshot newSnapshot, ITextSnapshot newVisualSnapshot, SnapshotPoint anchorPosition, Double verticalDistance, ViewRelativePosition relativeTo, Double effectiveViewportWidth, Double effectiveViewportHeight, Boolean preserveViewportTop)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.PerformLayout(ITextSnapshot newSnapshot, ITextSnapshot newVisualSnapshot)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextEditorFactoryService.InitializeTextView(IWpfTextView view)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextViewAdapter.Init_InitializeWpfTextView()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextViewAdapter.Init_OnActivation()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextViewAdapter.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsCompoundAction.OpenCompoundAction(String pszDescription)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Look in the Windows Application/System Event Logs and see if there's any suggestion of what went wrong. How do exe files built on your machine perform on your friend's? Sounds like a uninstall/reinstall of .Net framework might be a good idea.

Comment: I've tried attaching the process in Visual Studio and running a debug on it, but I can't seem to get anything out of it.  Even when I try to pause the application's runtime execution, it still closes.  I don't even have enough time to read the threads.  I will try uninstalling and reinstalling .NET again.  I have uninstalled/reinstalled 4.0 and 4.5, but nothing below.

Also, when I try to run without debug in VS the same issue occurs.  So it may have to do something with the vshost.exe environment giving it what it needs, but not outside.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back.  I checked my system event log and it appears my Software Protection stops about 5 minutes after I log on to my laptop.  Other than that, I received an error that looks like this:

"An exception has been encountered.  This may be caused by an extension.  You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\MyCompName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

Comment: In the activity log mentioned just above, the two errors that are in the log (very short version) are: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file." and "Construction of frame content failed."

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a simple repair of all my .NET frameworks solved the issue. It lead me to believe that .dlls being referenced needed to be both removed and repaired!  It appears that I can't upvote a comment, but I would if I could.